# Convert string to model

Tags: c#, parsing, dynamic, binding

Let's say I have this object:

```
public struct Line
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a file with lines following this syntax:

```
garbagedata|moregarbagedata|Name|garbagedata3|Value|garbagedatamaximums|Alias\n
```

Note that moregarbagedata[x] may or may not exist. A Regex is needed to extract the group-values.

What is easiest and most efficient way to turn this file's lines into a collection of `Line` objects? Order of this collection does not matter.

Comment: Is it a correct interpretation to say that the file is positional where the "value" you wanted stored in the Name property is the 3rd position, Value if 5th, and Alias is 7th?

Comment: Confused as to what you want, if moregarbagedata may not exist. Do you want positional, or do you want token based? Give us an example or two, telling us what the result should be.

Comment: how to tell between garbage and data?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are a couple of questions that needs to be asked here.

1. Can you change the file format?
2. Is there no way, you can specify a separate delimiter for key/value pairs?
   {value:garbage,alias:someotherGarbage},{value:secondGarbage....}
3. Are the lines (Environment.NewLine) the only way packets are separated?

If the answer to 1 is true, 
then you can use XmlSerializer and Serialize and Deserialize your objects to and fro.

If the answer for 2 is true,
then you could look at parsing the file manually using regex or reading line by line and just looking for Value: and then assume that the next item is the value of "Value"

if the answer for 3 is true,
Possibly the same answer as 2.

I hope this helps.