# Split string... tersely

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Convert string to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911732/c-convert-string-to-model)

Let's say I need to take a string and turn it into an array. This string has a single universal character to denote a new element. For example, I want to turn this string:

```
var s = "first|second|third";
```

Into this array:

```
var segments = new[]
{
    "first",
    "second",
    "third"
};
```

Is there an easier way to do it than this:

```
var segments = s.Split(new char[] { '|' });
```

I feel uncomfortable writing `(new char[] { '|' }`. I feel like there's probably this method, but I can't find its signature:

```
var segments = s.Split('|');
```

Comment: I just posted an answer over at your other question. It's bad form to ask the same question in a new post right away as others may be in the process of responding to your original question.

Comment: Stocking is very different from stalking.

Comment: Did you actually TRY this? You'll find, as SamStephens has written, that your pretty much on the money.

Comment: CantSleepAgain, can you *please* stop prefacing your questions with the prevailing technology name?  We have this awesome tag system which takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is exactly what you just wrote!

```
var s = "first|second|third";
var segments = s.Split('|');
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write the EXACT same thing...